# How to create button that behaves as toggle button?

Tags: android, button, togglebutton

I want functionality of toggle button in simple button.like

```
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.x);
if(b.isChecked())
{
//do somthing
}
else
{
//do somthing
}
```

any one have any logic in mind ?i dont want toggle button so please help.

Comment: why to use button ? u can use checkbox out there with ur own bg

Comment: why don't you want to use a `toggle button`?

Comment: no requirement is only for button so plz help i want to pair buttons in horizontalscrollview and in one of the button i want togglebutton functionality ,i ussed togglebutton but there exist alignment problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the `setTag(Object o)` and `getTag()` attributes for button..

By `default` in **xml** set the tag as "on"(according to your need):

And then in **JAVA**:

```
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(b.getTag().toString().trim().equals("on"))
                {
                      b.setTag("off");

                      //And your neceaasary code
                }
                else if(b.getTag().toString().trim().equals("off"))
                {
                      b.setTag("on");

                      //And your neceaasary code
                }


           }
       });
```

Comment: Thanks man,but i want to know why the same logic not works in boolean?

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply `onClickListener` combined with a boolean to remember the state on your button this way:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
boolean state = false;
button.setText(state?"state true":"state false");
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 if (state)
                    state = false;
                 else
                    state = true;

                 button.setText(state?"state true":"state false");
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 2):

Its is better to use CheckBox and you can make CheckBox look like a button by changing it Background. See [this](http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/05/customizing-checkboxes-in-android.html) link, it might help.